# How to prevent points from sinking into the surface with "Distribute Points on Faces"?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: Here ist the Problem.]I am using Blender 4.0.2 and Geometry Nodes to distribute objects on the surface of another object. However, the distributed objects sink into the surface of the other object. I want them to stay on the surface without being cut in half.

Additional Information:

Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot of the problem ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added a screenshot.

Comment: How precise do you want your instances to be on the surface ? Exact point of contact, or a bit of sinking is ok or even wanted ?

Comment: Remember that the points distributed on the faces are literally right on the face. That point is where the _origin point_ of your instanced object will be placed when it is instanced. If the origin of your instance object is right in the middle of the geometry, then the geometry will be instanced with half of it "above" the face, and half "below".

Comment: @Lutzi Thank you for your reply. No, it doesn't have to be exact. A little bit of sinking is okay.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thank you for your reply. I was just wondering if there's another way to approach this.  Even though I can adjust the origin point to make the objects sit on the surface, it seems like they might sink back in a bit if I randomize their rotation afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

#### Offset instances along surface normal

The easiest way to do that would be by offsetting the instances along the normals of the donut (blue arrows below). *Distribute Points on Faces* conveniently provides a *Normal* output, which is exactly what we need.

This method is assuming your objects are spherical. In this case, this solution is *perfect*. But the more your objects differ from a spherical shape, the less this method will work. In that case, you should seek another method.

Here is the setup

[image: Offset of instances along normal]

The idea is quite simple : take the normal vector (which length is always 1) and scale it to the amount we need. Use it as offset on instances.

Additionnaly, I've added the scaling factor as input of the *Geometry Node* modifier, so that you can easily tweak how much you offset the instances in other views and panels.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. I

In case I ever work with non-spherical objects, what method would you recommend?

Comment: I'd say there are 2 cases, convex objects (not your case) and concave objects (your case). Convex can still be simple, but concave can be tricky. I'll try to formulate an answer for the convex case.